# Words to use to confirm an amount for a task

Tags: word-usage, american-english, sentence

Someone wants a task to be done by me. And before picking I want to quote an amount say 50$ for it.
So some ways to quote an amount is  :

1. Are you fine with 50$ for this task ?
2. Will 50$ work for you ?

Are above lines correct ? Any better way to convey the same ?

Comment: Note that the convention is to put the dollar sign before the number: $50, not 50$.

Answer (score 1):

Both of those are acceptable. There are a lot of different ways you could say it!

"I could do it for $50. Does that sound good?"

"Does $50 seem fair to you?"

"I think $50 would be reasonable, if you agree?"

Etc. Etc. As I said, there are many different ways you could say it. If I had to pick one of your two, I'd go with the second one, because it sounds a bit simpler, more natural, and more relaxed to me. But there is absolutely nothing wrong with your first option!

Comment: In the above you mentioned  - I could do it for $50.                                                         Shouldnt it be - I can do it for 50$.    Just confirming the use of could and can here                                                           which one is correct

Comment: _could_ sounds more polite.

Comment: 1) can you check if that link works ?   2) could you check if that link works    are both 1 and 2 correct. As i understand since could sounds more polite so 2 will be a better choice. correct me